# Synth 8-2715 syntax error near

Tags: vhdl

I'm designing a basic Low Fuel Detector that turns on when the fuel is 1/3 empty or lower. My code is as follows:

```
ENTITY LFDetector_behav IS
PORT (Fuel3, Fuel2, Fuel1, Fuel0: IN std_logic;
     FuelWarningLight: OUT std_logic);
END LFDetector_behav;

ARCHITECTURE Behavior OF LFDetector_behav IS
BEGIN
 PROCESS (Fuel3, Fuel2, Fuel1, Fuel0)
 BEGIN
 FuelWarningLight <= [(NOT(Fuel3)) AND (NOT(Fuel2))] OR [(NOT(Fuel1)) AND (NOT(Fuel0))] AFTER 5.8 ns; 
 END PROCESS; 
END Behavior;
```

I get an error near my FuelWarningLight assignment and I dont understand why, I created other designs with the exact same format that worked perfectly. 
Thanks.

Comment: same *format* ? But why does format matter here? We need to fix the logic of it right?

Comment: There's an easy VHDL syntax issue here. Square brackets are not allowed here. Your code isn't a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and your logic doesn't look correct. Is Fuel3 ... Fuel0 a binary encoded value?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where your error is occuring (synth or sim), but the `after` keyword is not synthesisable. I'm also not sure if you have intended for this to be fully combinational or not.

Possibly try the following:

```
ARCHITECTURE Behavior OF LFDetector_behav IS
BEGIN
 PROCESS (Fuel3, Fuel2, Fuel1, Fuel0)
 BEGIN
 FuelWarningLight <= ((not Fuel3) AND (not Fuel2)) OR ((not Fuel1) AND (not Fuel0)); 
 END PROCESS; 
END Behavior;
```

Consider using clocked processes, as below (I haven't actually synth'd this, so apologies if there are any errors).

```
ENTITY LFDetector_behav IS
PORT (clk, Fuel3, Fuel2, Fuel1, Fuel0: IN std_logic;
     FuelWarningLight: OUT std_logic);
END LFDetector_behav;

ARCHITECTURE Behavior OF LFDetector_behav IS
BEGIN
 PROCESS (clk)
 BEGIN
  if rising_edge(clk) then
     FuelWarningLight <= ((not Fuel3) AND (not Fuel2)) OR ((not Fuel1) AND (not Fuel0)); 
  end if;
 END PROCESS; 
END Behavior;
```

Comment: With or without the plethora of redundant parentheses pairs or the ignored waveform element delay time expression the expression providing the projected output waveform value to [FuelWarningLight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3shMC.png) is incorrect.

Comment: True, there are redundant parentheses; I effectively replaced his [ ]. However, I removed the waveform element delay as I assumed it was a synth issue (based on the question title). I don't know what Fuel0..Fuel3 represent exactly, so I haven't bothered to extrapolate.